# Why can "X" be the last character of output?

Tags: c, fork, pid

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    if (fork() == fork()){

        fprintf(stderr, "Z");
    }
    else {
        if (waitpid((pid_t)-1,NULL,0)!=-1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Y");

        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "X");
        }
    }
}
```

I was studying this program and I found out "ZYYX" can be the output. I don't quite understand why. In my understanding, there are four process in total, parent->parent, parent->child, child->parent, child->parent. And there is no doubt child->child prints Z. And child->parent prints Y after child->child prints Z. And parent->parent should wait until parent->child prints X. So why it is possible that X is printed as the last character of the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that waitpid waits for any child process, so if ZY has been printed out, then Y can be printed out immediately since it has waited for "Y". Thus, X can be printed as the last character.

Comment: And ZYYX is the unique pattern with X in last position.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've seen `if (fork() == fork())` used in code before — congratulations!  I'm not wholly convinced by your tracking; I'd want to see the PID of each process included in any printing it did, and I'd want a newline at the end of each output.  Also, there's at least one process not waited for in the original code.

Here's a rewrite which reports the PID of the process doing each print operation.  Some of the processes exit with non-zero statuses, mainly to make it a little more interesting in the output.  The code tracks the corpses detected and reports on their status.  It also introduces a loop to clean up dead children.  The original process has a child that is not cleaned up otherwise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (fork() == fork())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Z(%d)\n", (int)getpid());
        return 23;
    }
    else
    {
        int corpse;
        int status;
        if ((corpse = waitpid((pid_t)-1, &status, 0)) != -1)
            fprintf(stderr, "Y(%d) - PID %d 0x%.4X\n", (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "X(%d)\n", (int)getpid());
            return 37;
        }
        while ((corpse = waitpid((pid_t)-1, &status, 0)) != -1)
            fprintf(stderr, "Q(%d) - PID %d 0x%.4X\n", (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
X(16551)
Y(16547) - PID 16551 0x2500
Z(16552)
Y(16550) - PID 16552 0x1700
Q(16547) - PID 16550 0x0000
```

Answer (score 0):

As you note, there will be 4 process, based on the two forks, and each will print one letter:

```
1st fork  2nd fork    prints                   PP
parent    parent        Y                     /  \
parent    child         X                   CP    PC
child     parent        Y                    \
child     child         Z                     CC
```

The graph on the left shows the parent/child relationships -- `/` is the first fork and `\` is the second fork(s).

So CC prints `Z` because both forks return 0, while PC prints `X`.  The other two both wait for a child to exit, then print `Y`.  In the cas of CP, there's only one child, so that `Y` will always be after the `Z`, but PP has two childre, so that `Y` might be after the `ZY` or after the `X`.  Either is possible.  So you can get any of

```
XYZY   PC,PP,CC,CP
XZYY   PC,CC,PP,CP or PC,CC,CP,PP
ZXYY   CC,PC,PP,CP or CC,PC,CP,PP
ZYXY   CC,CP,PC,PP
ZYYX   CC,CP,PP,PC
```